# How can I change action bar title with different style in different fragments?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, fragment

I am trying to change my 2 fragments action bar's with different titles. However, I am getting variable `fragment` might not have been initialized error in these lines:

`ProfileFragment fragment = (ProfileFragment) fragment.get(0)`;

```
StartingTestFragment fragment2 = (StartingTestFragment) fragment2.get(0);
```

in `CombineFragmentActivity` in `onPageSelected` method.Thanks for helps.

**CombineFragmentActivity.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Gravity;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;

public class CombineFragmentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.combine_fragment_activity);
        initialisePaging();
    }

    private void initialisePaging() {

        List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();
        fragments.add(new StartingTestFragment());
        fragments.add(new ProfileFragment());
        mPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter1(this.getSupportFragmentManager(),fragments);

        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        pager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

        pager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener(){
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                if(position == 0) {
                    ProfileFragment fragment = (ProfileFragment) fragment.get(0);
                    fragment.setActionBarTitle("Profil");
                } else {
                    StartingTestFragment fragment2 = (StartingTestFragment) fragment2.get(0);
                    fragment2.setActionBarTitle("Anasayfa");
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }

        });
    }
}
```

**ProfileFragment.java**

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    public ProfileFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    public static ProfileFragment newInstance() {
        ProfileFragment fragment = new ProfileFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);

    }

    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        Typeface ubuntu_MI = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),"Ubuntu-MI.ttf");
        Typeface ubuntu_L = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),"Ubuntu-L.ttf");
        Typeface ubuntu_R = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),"Ubuntu-R.ttf");


        /**
         * Be carefull when trying to find a view element from a layout if the name is already defined in any layout
         * AndroidStudio will not hint an error and you will end up with with ugly null pointer error
        TextView question = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView7);
        question.setTypeface(ubuntu_R);
         TextView info = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView6);
         info.setTypeface(ubuntu_R);

         */


    }
    public void setActionBarTitle(String title) {
        Typeface ubuntu_MI = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),"Ubuntu-MI.ttf");
        // Get the ActionBar
        android.support.v7.app.ActionBar ab = ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();


        // Create a TextView programmatically.
        TextView tv = new TextView(getActivity());

        // Create a LayoutParams for TextView
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, // Width of TextView
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); // Height of TextView

        // Apply the layout parameters to TextView widget
        tv.setLayoutParams(lp);

        // Set text to display in TextView
        // This will set the ActionBar title text
        tv.setText(title);

        // Set the text color of TextView
        // This will change the ActionBar title text color
        tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFF5EE"));

        // Center align the ActionBar title
        tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

        // Set the serif font for TextView text
        // This will change ActionBar title text font
        tv.setTypeface(ubuntu_MI);

        // Underline the ActionBar title text
        // tv.setPaintFlags(tv.getPaintFlags()| Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);

        // Set the ActionBar title font size
        tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,24);

        // Display a shadow around ActionBar title text
        //tv.setShadowLayer(
        //      1.f, // radius
        //    2.0f, // dx
        //  2.0f, // dy
        //  Color.parseColor("#FF8C00") // shadow color
        //);

        // Set the ActionBar display option
        ab.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);

        // Finally, set the newly created TextView as ActionBar custom view
        ab.setCustomView(tv);
    }
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    //Action Bar' daki settings kısmına basıldığında ne yapacağını söylüyoruz.
        if(item.getItemId() == R.id.settings){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Ayarlara basıldı", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_profile_activity, menu);

    }
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }

}
```

**StartingTestFragment.java**

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class StartingTestFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    private Spinner spinner;
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;



    public StartingTestFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    public static StartingTestFragment newInstance() {
        StartingTestFragment fragment = new StartingTestFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_startingtest, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        spinner = (Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),R.array.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,R.layout.spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);

        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);


        Typeface ubuntu_L = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),"Ubuntu-L.ttf");
        Typeface ubuntu_R = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),"Ubuntu-R.ttf");

        TextView info = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView6);
        TextView question = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView7);

        info.setTypeface(ubuntu_R);
        question.setTypeface(ubuntu_R);



    }
    public void setActionBarTitle(String title) {
        Typeface ubuntu_MI = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),"Ubuntu-MI.ttf");
        // Get the ActionBar
        android.support.v7.app.ActionBar ab = ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();


        // Create a TextView programmatically.
        TextView tv = new TextView(getActivity());

        // Create a LayoutParams for TextView
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, // Width of TextView
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); // Height of TextView

        // Apply the layout parameters to TextView widget
        tv.setLayoutParams(lp);

        // Set text to display in TextView
        // This will set the ActionBar title text
        tv.setText(title);

        // Set the text color of TextView
        // This will change the ActionBar title text color
        tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFF5EE"));

        // Center align the ActionBar title
        tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

        // Set the serif font for TextView text
        // This will change ActionBar title text font
        tv.setTypeface(ubuntu_MI);

        // Underline the ActionBar title text
        // tv.setPaintFlags(tv.getPaintFlags()| Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);

        // Set the ActionBar title font size
        tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,24);

        // Display a shadow around ActionBar title text
        //tv.setShadowLayer(
        //      1.f, // radius
        //    2.0f, // dx
        //  2.0f, // dy
        //  Color.parseColor("#FF8C00") // shadow color
        //);

        // Set the ActionBar display option
        ab.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);

        // Finally, set the newly created TextView as ActionBar custom view
        ab.setCustomView(tv);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                // Whatever you want to happen when the first item gets selected
                break;
            case 1:
                // Whatever you want to happen when the second item gets selected
                break;
            case 2:
                // Whatever you want to happen when the thrid item gets selected
                break;

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
}
```

> ERROR: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                         java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   com.example.khas.memorizingwords.ProfileFragment cannot be cast to
>   com.example.khas.memorizingwords.StartingTestFragment
>                                                                at com.example.khas.memorizingwords.CombineFragmentActivity$1.onPageSelected(CombineFragmentActivity.java:46)
>                                                                at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.dispatchOnPageSelected(ViewPager.java:1862)
>                                                                at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.scrollToItem(ViewPager.java:625)
>                                                                at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:609)
>                                                                at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onTouchEvent(ViewPager.java:2176)
>                                                                at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7127)
>                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2170)
>                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1905)
>                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
>                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1919)
>                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
>                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1919)
>                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
>                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1919)
>                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
>                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1919)
>                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
>                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1919)
>                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
>                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1919)
>                                                                at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1925)
>                                                                at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1379)
>                                                                at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2396)
>                                                                at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:60)
>                                                                at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1873)
>                                                                at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7307)
>                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3172)
>                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3117)
>                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4153)
>                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4132)
>                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4224)
>                                                                at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:171)
>                                                                at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
>                                                                at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
>                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
>                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
>                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
>                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
>                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: try this github example... https://github.com/tekinarslan/AndroidMaterialDesignToolbar

Comment: thanks but the structure of the projects are different. Do you know how to fix the problem?

Comment: which of problems?

Comment: the variable 'fragment' might not have been initialized

Comment: you are wrong using fragments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fragment variable is not initialized and you are caling get on it. Also this is not the correct way. Try below code

```
@Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    if(position == 0) {
                        ProfileFragment fragment = (ProfileFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().get(1)
                        fragment.setActionBarTitle("Profil");
                    } else {
                        StartingTestFragment fragment2 = (StartingTestFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().get(0);
                        fragment2.setActionBarTitle("Anasayfa");
                    }

                }
```

This is a better version and more general

```
@Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            Fragment fragment1 = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().get(position);
                if(fragment1 instanceof ProfileFragment) {
                    ProfileFragment fragment = (ProfileFragment) fragment1;
                    fragment.setActionBarTitle("Profil" );
                }
                else{
                    StartingTestFragment fragment = (StartingTestFragment) fragment1;
                    fragment.setActionBarTitle("Anasayfa");
                }
            } 

        }
```

This is the way to change title

```
setActionBarTitle(YOUR_TITLE);
```

use this instead of fragment.setACtionBarTitle

I think it is not guaranteed what the order of fragments is when retreived from manager. So simply do this

```
@Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                Fragment fragment1 = fragments.get(position);
                if(fragment1 instanceof ProfileFragment) {
                    ProfileFragment fragment = (ProfileFragment) fragment1;
                    fragment.setActionBarTitle("Profil" );
                }
                else{
                    StartingTestFragment fragment = (StartingTestFragment) fragment1;
                    fragment.setActionBarTitle("Anasayfa");
                }

            }
```

**Note: Make your fragments list final by doing this**

```
final List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: When I try this, program stops. I updated the question with fatal error.

Comment: @D.Y see the edit, I swapped get(0) and get(1), this will surely work !

Comment: I have made another edit please try that too once !!

Comment: I tried it and in getActivity() part, there is an error. cannot resolve method getActivity()

Comment: @D.Y getActivity gives context, but you are already in activity so you don't need it just use setActionBarTitle(YOUR_TITLE); Should work now

Comment: but I have one question. It looks on the screen in reverse. I mean in ProfileFragment the title must be "Profil". However, it looks like "Anasayfa". Why is that? @varunkr

Comment: it works okey in Nexus S but it work reverse in Nexus 5

Comment: @D.Y Are you using the first code or the second one where I am using instanceOf?

Comment: @D.Y OK, I see it may be because the fragmentSupportmanager might not guarantee the order of fragments. SO it is better not to depend on it. Please see the edits. This would work 100%. Please inform me once about this. Also can you upvote my answer as well, will help with the reputation. :)

Comment: I tried right away. However, there is a red line on "fragments"

Comment: OK.. android studio wanted me to make the fragments final variable, so I did it final.. The problem is solved 100% :) thank you so much :). Of course I will upvote your answer only if you can tell me how to do it:) @varunkr

Comment: @D.Y Thanks and it is important that you understand what the problem with each of the edits was, until the final worked, happy coding !!